# Issue with retrieving image

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

So I am using `file-expressupload` and when a user creates an account, they upload the photo and shows uploaded in the uploads directory. In the path I included the direct path, so the uploading is good, but no image displayed on the webpage. WTF, lol, anyway, what is the issue?

Code for storing user result:

[image]

I tried including the path to uploads and it worked, but not showing image

```
const User = require('../models/Users')
const path = require('path')

module.exports = (req,res, result) =>{
    let image = req.files.image;
    image.mv(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'public/uploads', image.name), async (error) => {
        await User.create(req.body, (error, user) =>{
            if(error){
                const validationErrors = Object.keys(error.errors).map(key => error.errors[key].message)
                req.flash('validationErrors',validationErrors)
                req.flash('data',req.body)
                return res.redirect('/register')
            }
            result({
                ...req.body,
                image: '/uploads/' + image.name,
                userid: req.session.userId
            })
            res.redirect('/')
        })
    })
}
```

Broken image:

[image]